# How To Delete a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I am at the moment trying to delete a LEFT OUTER JOIN I created for a CMS website on PHP my LEFT OUTER JOIN looks like this:

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT filename FROM phpland LEFT OUTER JOIN 
images ON phpland.image_id = images.id WHERE phpland.id = '$pageid' ";
```

In this case phpland and images are the name of my tables and the `$pageid` is the id I'm passing to it, yet it seems to work no problem but when I attempt to delete it I'm trying:

```
DELETE filename from phpland AS filename LEFT OUTER JOIN images 
ON phpland.image_id = images.id WHERE phpland.id = '$pid' "
```

Same situation Im passing the ID and I'm even echoing the ID on PHP to make sure is the ID I wish to delete but it tells me the ID is ambiguous, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong the primary Key on the table `images.id` is a foreign key on phpland as `image_id`.

I do hope this was not confusing for anyone, any type of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? Not all DBMS support a JOIN in a DELETE statement

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.  Are you trying to delete rows from the table `phpland` if there is a matching row in table `images` for that `$pid`?  And in your first query, `filename` is a column name but in your second query attempt it is a table alias.

Comment: Im using MYSQLI you are right I didn't mention that, and yes perhaps I don't have the right syntax, however what I would like to do is to delete the outer join previously created at the beginning which I'm sure is working cause it displays the images properly on teh website But I'm not sure how to approach that thanks a lot for your input

Answer (score 1):

Why do you reference to table images when your id to delete is already in phpland?

And your syntax for deletion is worng. Try:

```
DELETE FROM phpland 
WHERE phpland.id = '$pageid'
```

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html